# Реализация отскока мячей при столкновении друг с другом

Tags: javascript, html, css, ооп, объекты

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<style>


</style>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>
<script>
var Ball = function() { 
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.xSpeed = -2;
  this.ySpeed = 3;
};


var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 3, true);//присваиваю координаты,радиус мяча
};

Ball.prototype.move = function() { //рисваиваю скорость по координатам
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;
};

Ball.prototype.checkCollision = function() { //проверка столкновения с границами поля
  if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
  }
  if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
    this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  }
};
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
var ball = new Ball();
var ball2 = new Ball();
var ball3 = new Ball();
var ball4 = new Ball();
var ball5 = new Ball();
var ball6 = new Ball();
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;


setInterval(function() {  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ball.draw();
  ball.move();
  ball.checkCollision();

  ball2.draw();
  ball2.move();
  ball2.checkCollision();

  ball3.draw();
  ball3.move();
  ball3.checkCollision();

  ball4.draw();
  ball4.move();
  ball4.checkCollision();

  ball5.draw();
  ball5.move();
  ball5.checkCollision();

  ball6.draw();
  ball6.move();
  ball6.checkCollision();

  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно проверять координаты с каждым шаром

```js
var index=0;
var Ball = function() {
  this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  this.xSpeed = -2;
  this.ySpeed = 3;
  this.index = index; index++;
};


var circle = function(x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

Ball.prototype.draw = function() {
  circle(this.x, this.y, 3, true);//присваиваю координаты,радиус мяча
};

Ball.prototype.move = function() { //рисваиваю скорость по координатам
  this.x += this.xSpeed;
  this.y += this.ySpeed;
};

Ball.prototype.checkCollision = function() { //проверка столкновения с границами поля
  if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width) {
    this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
  }
  if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
    this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
  }
  balls.forEach(b=>{if(b.index!=this.index && Math.abs(b.x-this.x)<10 && Math.abs(b.y-this.y)<10) {b.xSpeed=-b.xSpeed;b.ySpeed=-b.ySpeed;this.xSpeed=-this.xSpeed;}})
};
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
var balls = [new Ball(),new Ball(),new Ball(),new Ball(),new Ball(),new Ball()];
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

setInterval(function() {  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  balls.forEach(b=>{b.draw();b.move();b.checkCollision();});
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height);
}, 30)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не очень знаю JS, но по идее надо просто брать радиус двух шаров и при растоянии между ними меньше суммарной суммы радиусов, просто отражать скорость мячей(это если не надо учитывать массу шаров, то есть она равна у всех)
По идее тебе в идеале объявить массив с мячами и пробегаясь по ним, сравнивать положения и если они пересекаются, то делать отталкивание.